# Run program as different, password protected user in Win 7 wo/ PW prompt

Tags: windows-7, runas

In order to increase security while browsing, I would like to launch the browser as a separate user. Several people suggested the `runas` command, but it lacks the ability on purpose to **pass the password in the command line**. `savecred` provides the option to save it for business editions, but not everyone in my family has one. Entering the password every time is not an option - people won't use it then.

- Can I achieve running the browser as another, password protected user without entering the password each time with a stock Windows 7 Home?
- If not, which open source or freeware program does provide this functionality?

Comment: How exactly does this increase security?

Comment: @Ramhound I presume Stephan intends to run the browser as a lower-permissioned user, e.g., as a guest rather than as a member of the administrators group.

Comment: exactly. BSI (German department of security in information system) 'suggests' it http://www.heise.de/security/meldung/BSI-Test-Verwundbarkeit-von-Windows-Rechnern-im-Netz-1748721.html

Comment: @NicoleHamilton - IE can be run by a normal user level account.  I don't see how running say IE as another user achieves anything.  Any user level exploit would still result in an infection.

Comment: @Ramhound The whole objective of any hacker is to get his code to run on your system by way of an exploit.   Assuming he's successful, it still matters whether his code runs as guest versus admin.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton - I am saying that your user's account should already have the lowest privilage required to function.  So unless there is a specific reason another user's profile should be used what the author is trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @Ramhound And what I'm saying is most of us don't run as guest all day.  We're probably members of the admin group, just not running elevated.  We do that because that is the privilege level we need to get our jobs done.  But that's more privilege than is typically needed for browsing, which is what Stefan is concerned about.

Comment: I should note the http://www.heise.de/security/meldung/BSI-Test-Verwundbarkeit-von-Windows-Rechnern-im-Netz-1748721.html actually said something else entirely. It basically said don't use an administrator account it did NOT say to run a browser as another user while logged into a administrator account.

Comment: He is asking about a HOME PC.  Using a regular non-administrator account should be enough for your typical non-expert.

Answer (score 1):

It's not free, but I include an [`su` (superuser)](http://hamiltonlabs.com/UserGuide/Utilities/su.htm) utility with [Hamilton C shell](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm) that will do what you want.  Full disclosure:  I'm the author.

Comment: yeah, 89$ is not free - especially considering it's a simple call of one function: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/29/271551.aspx

Comment: It's not that simple.  My `su` took me over 4000 lines of C.  But I appreciate that if you need something free, my stuff is not.  Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

create a file called program.bat
now write following in this file and adapt for your case

```
cmd /C echo YOUR_PASS | runas /user:USERNAME \"C:\Program Files\program.exe\"
```

Comment: If it worked, please do not forget to accept this answer as the right answer by checking the ✓ on the left of this.

Comment: does not work. See: http://pastebin.com/xyLwWf5C